# Why does loading a dll result in "duplicates not allowed" error?

Tags: devexpress, c++builder

My Embarcadero upgrade woes continue. I am trying to load a dll via the `LoadLibary` call, but it fails with `First chance exception at $74F3CA42. Exception class EListError with message 'Duplicates not allowed'.` Call stack at the time of exception below. We upgraded from RAD 10.1 to 11.1. Both the calling exe and the dll is C++ and  the cbproj file is created from scratch in the new version, which fixed many other errors. Both the exe and the dll had DevExpress C++ components. Other exes are able to load the dll, but something in this exe or a configured package seems causing the issue.

```
:74f3ca42 KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x62
:55c2c179 CustomIPTransport280.@System@Generics@Collections@%TDictionary__2$5_GUIDp17System@TMetaClass%@Add$qqrrx5_GUIDxp17System@TMetaClass + 0x4d
:555c923e IndyIPCommon280.@Ippeercommon@initialization$qqrv + 0x5e
:322599e1 ; B:\Build\CC32280MT.DLL
:32259f88 CC32280MT.__wstartupd + 0xc0
:07c96f5a ; System.Win.Stdvcl
:7702dd42 ntdll.RtlActivateActivationContextUnsafeFast + 0xe2
:77031843 ; ntdll.dll
:770319b1 ; ntdll.dll
:77032255 ntdll.RtlIsCriticalSectionLockedByThread + 0xb5
:7702e272 ; ntdll.dll
:7702deb6 ntdll.LdrLoadDll + 0xf6
:74f21bc6 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll
:74f3cca1 KERNELBASE.LoadLibraryW + 0x11
:00481026 TfrmTkTicketInquiry::actEmailExecute(this=:04639B90, Sender=:02B24A60)
:50173bfa rtl280.@System@Classes@TBasicAction@Execute$qqrv + 0x12
:5650799b vcl280.@Vcl@Controls@TControl@Perform$qqruiuii + 0x27
:5650c6ad vcl280.@Vcl@Controls@TWinControl@IsControlMouseMsg$qqrr24Winapi@Messages@TWMMouse + 0xb5
:56595367 ; B:\Build\vcl280.bpl
:5650c3f7 vcl280.@Vcl@Controls@TWinControl@MainWndProc$qqrr24Winapi@Messages@TMessage + 0x2f
:50174a32 rtl280.@System@Classes@TDataModule@WriteHeight$qqrp22System@Classes@TWriter + 0x22
:75070f1b USER32.AddClipboardFormatListener + 0x4b
:75067eca ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USER32.dll
:75065c3a ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USER32.dll
:75065a00 USER32.DispatchMessageW + 0x10
:5664d69c vcl280.@Vcl@Forms@TApplication@ProcessMessage$qqrr6tagMSG + 0xf8
:75437464 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SHELL32.DLL
```

Comment: The error appears to be coming from the `initialization` section of the `IPPeerCommon` unit, trying to register a `GUID`+`TMetaClass` into a `TDictionary` and failing because the `GUID` already exists in the dictionary. Does the DLL in question have runtime packages enabled, and do other DLLs/BPLs in your app also have runtime packages enabled and use that same unit?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The dll has runtime packages (they are the same as the calling exe). There are no other dll/bpls explicit calls.

Comment: OK, then is the EXE using the `IPPeerCommon` unit? In any case, if the DLL is using runtime packages, then the DLL should be changed to a BPL instead, and loaded with `LoadPackage()` instead of `LoadLibrary()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Changing to bpl will be a bigger architectural change. Will try if nothing else work. I tried removing Indy libraries from the dll before, but still keep getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the offending runtime packages from the dll. Seems like I missed one of the packages in the previous try. Remy's comment also helped to confirm the cause of the issue. Now on to the next woe :)